# Python3: reading utf8 encoded bytestrings

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, utf-8

My program uses the output from "iwlist scan" to generate a report.
It works fine except when the network name (ESSID) contains non-Ascii characters.
IEEE802.11 state that ESSID may contain UTF8 characters. However these essid are reported by iwlist as an encoded bytestring. Example:
      ESSID:"f\xC3\xAAte"
\xC3\xAA is effectively the UTF-8 encoding of "ê"
I can't find a way to specify to 'open' that these bytestrings should be automatically converted into UTF-8 characters.
Question: what is the most pythonic way to solve my problem?

PS: as a test case, I put the following line in a file (say xx):
*ESSID:"f\xC3\xAAte"*
and I execute:
*open( 'xx','rb').read().decode('UTF-8')*
and my result is:
*'ESSID:"f\xC3\xAAte"\n'*

Comment: Is `b"f\xC3\xAAte".decode("utf-8")` what you want?

Comment: @stepan: yes and no. Please look at the added test case.

Comment: Your test case is not representative of your actual problem, unless the string returned has the 4-byte sequence `\xC3` in it.

Comment: I'm not sure your test case is of any use. You have actual quotes and backslashes in there, which means you'll have to call `eval()` on it or something like that.

Comment: @mark: I don't understand why my test case is not representative. The double quotes and the backslashes are actually coming from iwlist, verbatim.

Comment: @lenz: please see comment to mark. I was expecting a simple solution and eval() on external data is a risky solution. All I need is a simple way to "unescape" what iwlist generated in it's output.

Comment: I said that because it's unusual to see a string in that form. It's also the form you see when you inspect a string instead of using `print` on it, so many people make that mistake.

Comment: If the quotes and backslashes are actually part of the data, then `eval()` is a simple, but risky solution, as you say. The [*unicode_escape* codec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#python-specific-encodings) helps you with the `\xNN` escapes (`"\xC3".decode('unicode_escape')`), but for the quotes you'll probably have to write a regex.

Comment: @stepan: the reason your example works is that the bytestring specifier (b) does some subtle cleanup, silently.

Comment: @stepan: (sorry, a portion was lost). the reason your example works is that Python seems to do some subtle cleanup, silently. The string "f\xC3\xAAte" seems to have a length of 11 but len( "f\xC3\xAAte") returns 5. Every \xnn sequence is replaced by a single byte before processing.In the example, the two bytes resulting from that cleanup are then converted to a single unicode-character by decode() and the final length (after decode) is 4. That subtle handling is not done if data come from reading a file.

Comment: @user3435121: try `open( 'xx','rb').read().decode('unicode_escape')`

Comment: Alternatively, if what you're printing is not escaped backslashes, but escapes, you might have a weird issue with double encoding. You might try encoding said string as latin-1 (to convert straight to bytes by ordinal), then decoding a utf-8, e.g. `"f\xC3\xAAte".encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8')` which produces `'fête'`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: your answer and the one from markRansom came in at approximately the same time and, surprise, both follow the same path. You can post as an answer to get a point.

Comment: I'm interested to learn more about unicode codecs. Is there a good tutorial somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a two-step process: convert the `\xNN` codes to the equivalent byte value, then convert those bytes from UTF-8 to Unicode characters. Python provides a `unicode_escape` codec to make the process simpler. Unfortunately you need an extra step - it won't convert the `\xNN` to bytes, it converts them to characters and you need to convert *those* back to the equivalent bytes.

So you end up with a 3-step conversion. Encoding to `latin1` is a hack to convert characters to bytes. It works because Unicode uses the Latin-1 encoding for its first 256 codepoints giving you a 1:1 mapping.

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    essid_raw = f.read()
    essid = essid_raw.decode('unicode_escape').encode('latin1').decode('utf-8')


>>> essid_raw = b'ESSID:"f\xC3\xAAte"'
>>> essid = essid_raw.decode('unicode_escape').encode('latin1').decode('utf-8')
>>> print(essid)
ESSID:"fête"
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood your problem:

Looks like your file doesn't have Unicode characters at all, but instead, it has an escaped string. So instead of one `ê` symbol you actually have 8 characters — `\xC3\xAA`. So instead of decoding from Unicode with `.decode("utf-8")` you should decode from unicode escape characters (`.decode('unicode_escape')`.

To try this I made a file with a string:

`ESSID:"f\xC3\xAAte"`

then this script prints the following:

```
>>> open( 'file','rb').read().decode('UTF-8')
ESSID:"f\xC3\xAAte"
```

And if you use unicode_escape instead, you will get

```
>>> open( 'file','rb').read().decode('unicode_escape')
ESSID:"fÃªte"
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. You're right when you say that the file is not Unicode. I'm trying to decode the output of iwlist; when the network name contains UTF-8, iwlist generate escaped characters that are difficult to decode. What you propose do not generate the right answer (the right answer is fête, 4 characters long).

Comment: @user3435121 try `essid.decode('unicode_escape').encode('latin1').decode('utf8')`.

Comment: @MarkRansom: you're the king mark! That's the kind of statement I was searching for. It's a very convoluted statement but it works fine. If you repost as an answer, I will show my gratitude.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering to myself.
Cannot find a python solution so I developed mine.
Method is to remove '\x' and convert 2 hex characters to a byte. Repeat for each \x.

```
def adapt( tb):
  # this function converts the weird UTF8 escaping used by 'iwlist scan'
  # iwlist outputs "f\xC3\xAAte" instead of "fête"
  # caution : input is not sanitized 
  i = 0
  while True:
    # suppress \x and replace the following 2 characters by their hex value 
    i = tb.find( b'\\\x', i)
    if i < 0: break
    tb = tb[:i] + bytes( [int( tb[ i+2:i+4], 16)]) + tb[i+4:]
    i += 1     # skip the preceding sequence
  return tb
```

Usage:

```
txt = adapt( open( 'xx','rb').read()).decode()
print( txt)
ESSID:"fête"
```

It is an ugly hack but it works fine. I would gladly like a nicer solution.
Thanks for your answers.

Comment: disregard this solution. The one from markRansom and shadowRanger is better and work fine.